# Set start and end of graph points dynamically

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts and in which I have by default today entire day data.
I would like to set start and end points dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: "http://localhost/data.php",
        success: function(response) {
        var pointstart=response.start_date;
            console.info(response.start_date+" "+response.end_date);
        $('#graph').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                zoomType: 'x'
              },
              xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                setExtremes: (response.start_date,response.end_date),
                tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
                dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                  month: '%e. %b',
                  year: '%b'
                }
              },
            series:[{
                pointStart      : pointstart,
                pointInterval   : 3600 * 1000,
                name: 'cc',
                data: response.data
            }]
                 });
            },
            cache: false
    });
});
```

Problem: I am not able to see graph from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59. I have per minute single record. Above graph showing me data from 12:48:01 to 23:59:01.
I am using this [test data](http://dpaste.com/2QQQX49).

Note: In some cases, I have multiple months data so values should need to set up dynamically based on ajax response start_date and end_date. By

Test data: http://dpaste.com/2QQQX49

Answer (score 6):

You can set xAxis extremes using min and max properties (Check here https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min, https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max). By default they are undefined and value is automatically calculated. That's why your chart is rendered from 12:48:01 to 23:59:01 - appropriately to your data.

Online example: https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/sL13nhfq/

```
   xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime',
     tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
     max: response.end_date,
     min: response.start_date,
     dateTimeLabelFormats: {
       month: '%e. %b',
       year: '%b'
     }
   }
```

Another approach is to use setExtremes method on xAxis object (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes). You can make it for e.g when load event occur:

Online example: https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/e42sx7pk/

```
  chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    zoomType: 'x',
    events: {
       load: function() {
         var chart = this;
         chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(response.start_date, response.end_date);
       }
    }
  }
```